# Add thousands separator in suggested tags

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching, ignored-tags, numbers

Is it possible to add thousands separator in suggested list of tags that appears when adding Favorite or Ignored tags?

To improve readability (of course) and to be coherent with the rest of the site.

An example below, feature-request item on list:[image]

Comment: Does this thousands separator have to be localized, based on the user's country of origin?

Comment: The site is en_US so the thousands separator that's used there would be appropriate IMO.

Comment: It would be great to have them localized. However since every number on SE is integer, I think that even if I use point as thousands separator, I can accept this :)

Comment: Moreover, also tooltip on username shows reputation without thousands separator..

Answer (score 5):

Yes, adding commas as thousands separators would improve readability, and they are already used elsewhere on these English-language websites.

---

- Here's an example for reputation:

[image: rep bar]

---

- And another:

[image: profile reputation]

---

- And a third:

[image: next to a question]

---

- And for question counts:

[image: total questions asked]