# Number-format on number of questions tagged in each tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, information-display

My first post here at meta, so please be gentle.

I love the Stack-site. They are clean and it's very simple to get the information you want. Everything seems very thought-through. One thing I've noticed however is that at the right side of tags (on a question or tag-overview), there is no thousand-separator on the number of questions tagged in that tag.

See for example this question: [How do I prevent the modification of a private field in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809293/)

On the tags on the right, I just see a bunch of random numbers. I really don't get any idea of how many questions we are talking about. I think it would be an improvement to add a separator here.

You can see the same at the tag-overview: https://stackoverflow.com/tags

EDIT: Or just see how `feature-request` looks on the right side of this post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a style choice and won't be changed. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165110/add-thousands-separator-in-suggested-tags http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92618/add-thousands-separator-to-profile-reputation-score http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146992/add-thousands-separator-to-numbers-in-the-badges-and-tags-sections http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120971/add-thousands-separators-to-the-numbers-of-votes-and-edits-displayed-on-the-user

Comment: @AlEverett: Many of the things in those threads have been fixed...

Comment: I suggest introducing the `k` and `M` notation used in rep: `java 376k`, `feature-request 12.8k`, `tags 3085`, etc.